# Difference of four-momentums in muon decay

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, conservation-laws, scattering

I am currently working on Exercise 7.8 from Schwartz's "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model." In the problem, we consider muon decay,

$$\mu^- \rightarrow e^- \overline{\nu}_e\nu_\mu$$

and we assume that $e^-$, $\overline{\nu}_\mu$, and $\nu_\mu$ are massless. For this exercise, our professor told us that if we assume that the muon neutrino is moving along the z-axis, then
$$(p_{\mu^-}-p_{\nu_\mu})^2 = m_{\mu^-}^2 - E_{\nu_\mu}m_{\mu^-}$$
where $p_{\mu^-}$ and $p_{\nu_\mu}$ are the four-momentums. I'm not sure why this is true. When I expanded the left hand side and used the relation $E^2 = m^2 + \vec{p}^2$, I got
$$m_{\mu^-}^2-2E_{\nu_\mu}(E_\mu - p_{\mu^-}^{(3)})$$
Was the hint incorrect?

For some context, in the problem we assume that $m_{W^-}$ is large, where $W^-$ is the intermediate massive boson. We want to compute $|\mathcal{M}|^2$. I made the deductions:
$$|\mathcal{M}|^2 = g^4\frac{1}{\Big((p_{\nu_\mu}-p_{\mu^-})^2 - m_{W^-}^2\Big)^2 } = \frac{g^4}{m_{W^-}^4}\frac{1}{\Big(1-\frac{(p_{\nu_\mu}-p_{\mu^-})^2}{m_{W^-}^2}\Big)^2} \approx \frac{g^4}{m_{W^-}^4}\Big(1+ 2\frac{(p_{\nu_\mu}-p_{\mu^-})^2}{m_{W^-}^2}\Big)$$
where $g$ is some coupling constant. The solution I have seen says that
$$|\mathcal{M}^2| \approx \frac{g^4}{m_{W^-}^4}\Big( 1+ 2\frac{m_\mu^2-m_\mu E_{\nu_\mu}}{m_{W^-}^2}\Big).$$

Comment: Is the muon at rest before decay?

Comment: Oh yeah! That will take care of things (up to a factor of 2)!